# Text on a picture, but like this one. How?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I've made a pure PHP script that uses GD library to put text on an image, text entered from a HTML form.
The problem is that i can't give the user the possibility to position the text properly.

I've found this good example http://lolkot.ru/lolmixer/#1369, it allows users to play with the text very easily with the mouse !

How is this possible ?
What technologies are used for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript [yui](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) (for drag and drop of the texts), [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) (for events and AJAX), server side generation of transparent png-s (containing texts)

Comment: You can also use most any JavaScript library that supports draggable elements. jQuery, Scriptaculous, etc

Comment: ... if you're insane.  [Someone else already did the hard work](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), after all.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to highlight that you don't need a library to do this, as everybody is too quick to recommend jQuery et al. And it's really not all that complicated if you know what you're doing. :)

Comment: I think recommending jQuery is never too quick. I think that jQuery is the best thing that happened to JavaScript ever. Every time when I write some jQuery code I am amazed how easy this is and thankful of how much of my work is saved.